# How can I have a stripe dynamic form for collecting billing address and name along with card details

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments

I'm using react hooks with typescript for stripe integration to the commercial website. and stripe Intent is getting created at backend using java spring can I update the stripe intent with billing address and name using stripe dynamic form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyasV.png)

obtained clientSecret and passed to elements options
here I'm confirming the payment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNlKP.png)

checked out some other solutions at online. But did not find solution that I can adapt.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element), based on your use of `confirmPayment`. The Payment Element automatically collects required billing information based on the customer country and selected payment method type. You can preview this on the page above by changing the country and payment method type to see the fields collected.

Other optional (non-[PCI](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance)) billing details can be collected by you in your own form and provided during confirmation using `payment_method_data[billing_details]` ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-confirmParams-payment_method_data-billing_details)).